# Instantiating objects foreach and mysqli results

Tags: php, class, mysqli

hopefully this can make sense.

I want to be able to do something like this

```
<?php
  require_once("inc/database_connection.php");
  require_once("classes/Users.php");

  $users = Users::GetAllUsers($dbConn);
  foreach($users as $user) {
     echo $user->GetUserName();
  }

?>
```

I see that it is available in code igniter's result() set function - http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html
                                                                              but I would really like to add it into my database class.

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: I dont know how to code it, or where to start looking for info

Comment: Read the chapter on defining classes in any PHP textbook or tutorial

Comment: That's not what I need help with, its inside the foreach

Comment: What's the problem? Return an array of `User` objects from `GetAllUsers()`.

Comment: But how do I instantiate a class for each result object?

Comment: Inside `GetAllUsers`, use `new User()` for each result that mysqli returns.

Comment: It works for when I just have $return[] = new User();

Comment: But what if I wanted to return mysqli resultset aswell?

Answer (score 1):

The `GetAllUser` method should contain something like:

```
$res = mysqli_query(...);
$results = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $results[] = new User($row['userid'], $row['username'], $row['email'], ...);
}
return $results;
```

Comment: would you recommend doing mysqli calls this way or not?

Comment: I don't personally write my PHP code using classes. But that's a personal style choice, probably because I've been programming since long before OOP became popular and I'm set in my ways. But if you find OOP useful for your code, go for it.